# Trouble tying everything together with main function using python

Tags: python

I am new to programing and am having trouble getting my main function to work. My print statement gives me the error:

> candidate is not defined

but shouldn't my `findBestCandidate` function provide it? What am I doing wrong?? Any help to get me in the right direction would be awesome!

```
def fileToList(filename):
    import os.path
    if os.path.isfile(filename) == True:
        file = open(filename, "r")
        strings = file.read().splitlines()
        file.close()
        return strings
    if os.path.isfile(filename) == False:
        return []

def returnFirstString(strings):
    string = ''
    if len(strings) != 0:
        string = string + strings[0]
    return string

def strandsAreNotEmpty(strand1,strand2):
    if len(strand1) != 0 and len(strand2) != 0:
        return True
    return False

def strandsAreEqualLengths(strand1,strand2):
    if len(strand1) == len(strand2):
        return True
    return False

def findLargestOverlap(target,candidate):
    if len(target) != len(candidate):
        return -1
    if len(target) == 0 or len(candidate) == 0:
        return -1
    c = ''
    ol = 0
    for char in candidate:
        c += char
        if target[(len(target)-len(c)):] == c:
            ol = len(c)
    return ol

def findBestCandidate(target,candidates):
    overlap = 0
    candidate = ''
    for can in candidates:
        ol = findLargestOverlap(target, can)
        if ol > overlap:
            overlap = ol
            candidate = can
    return (candidate, overlap)

def joinTwoStrands(target,candidate,overlap):
    return target+candidate[overlap:]

def main():
    target = input('Enter target strand filename:')
    candidates = input('Enter candidate strands filename:')
    fileToList(target)
    fileToList(candidates)
    findBestCandidate(target,candidates)
    print(joinTwoStrands(target,candidate,overlap))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: Read up on variable scope: http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

Comment: All of your functions `return` something but you're not capturing their values. set them to a variable (or variables) and then pass them to the function requiring them

Comment: i.e. `t, c = findBestCandidate(target, candidates)` `print(joinTwoStrands(target, t, c))`

Comment: Note, this question has nothing to do with the use of a main function.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure it out with you guidance and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your findBestCandidate function, you should call it like this, proceed on the same fashion for other function calls, i.e. storing the result in variables in main

```
def main():
    ...
    candidate, overlap = findBestCandidate(target,candidates)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to take the model you provided and implement it into my code!